# Which data layer / handling architecture or pattern to choose for a non-enterprise web application? (MVC / EF)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I need some help in making a design choice for my application. It’s a fairly straightforward web application, definitely not enterprise class or enterprise-anything.

The architecture is standard MVC 5 / EF 6 / C# ASP.NET, and the pages talk to a back-end database that’s in SQL server, and all the tables have corresponding entity objects generated from VS 2013 using the EF designer and I don’t see that changing anytime in the near future. Therefore creating super abstract “what if my database changes” etc. separations is possibly pointless. **I am a one-man operation so we're not talking huge teams etc.**

What I want is a clean way to do CRUD and query operations on my database, using DbContext and LINQ operations – but I’m not good with database related code design. Here are my approaches

**1.    Static class with methods -**  Should I create a static class (my DAL) that holds my datacontext and then provide functions that controllers can call directly

```
 e.g. MyStaticDBLib.GetCustomerById(id)
```

but this poses problems when we try to update records from disconnected instances (i.e. I create an object that from a JSON response and need to ‘update’ my table). The good thing is I can centralize my operations in a Lib or DAL file. This is also quickly getting complicated and messy, because I can’t create methods for every scenario so I end up with bits of LINQ code in my controllers, and bits handled by these LIB methods

**2.    Class with context, held in a singleton, and called from controller**

```
MyContext _cx = MyStaticDBLib.GetMyContext(“sessionKey”);
var xx = cx.MyTable.Find(id) ; //and other LINQ operations
```

This feels a bit messy as my data query code is in my controllers now but at least I have clean context for each session. The other thinking here is LINQ-to-SQL already abstracts the data layer to some extent as long as the entities remain the same (the actual store can change), so why not just do this?

**3.    Use a generic repository and unitofwork pattern** – now we’re getting fancy. I’ve read a bit about this pattern, and there’s so many different advises, including some strongly suggesting that EF6 already builds the repository into its context therefore this is overkill etc. It does feel overkill but need someone here to tell me that given my context

**4.    Something else? Some other clean way of handling basic database/CRUD**

Right now I have the library type approach (1. above) and it's getting increasingly messy. I've read many articles and I'm struggling as there's so many different approaches, but I hope the context I've given can elicit a few responses as to what approach may suit me. I need to keep it simple, and I'm a one-man-operation for the near future.

Comment: I see you put a lot of thought and effort into your question , this isn't really the place for opinion based questioins .  You can try http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not #1. The context is not thread safe and you certainly wouldn't want it as a static var in a static class. You're just asking for your application to explode.

Option 2 is workable as long as you ensure that your singleton is thread-safe. In other words, it'd be a singleton per-thread, not for the entire application. Otherwise, the same problems with #1 apply.

Option 3 is typical but short-sighted. The repository/unit of work patterns are pretty much replaced by having an ORM. Wrapping Entity Framework in another layer like this only removes many of the benefits of working with Entity Framework while simultaneously increasing the friction involved in developing your application. In other words, it's a lose-lose and completely unnecessary.

So, I'll go with #4. If the app is simple enough, just use your context directly. Employ a DI container to inject your context into the controller and make it request-scoped (new context per request). If the application gets more complicated or you just really, really don't care for having a dependency on Entity Framework, then apply a service pattern, where you expose endpoints for specific datasets your application needs. Inject your context into the service class(es) and then inject your service(s) into your controllers. Hint: your service endpoints should return fully-formed data that has been completely queried from the database (i.e. return lists and similar enumerables, not queryables).

Answer (score 0):

While Chris's answer is a valid approach, another option is to use a very simple concrete repository/service façade.  This is where you put all your data access code behind an interface layer, like IUserRepository.GetUsers(), and then in this code you have all your Entity Framework code.

The value here is separation of concerns, added testability (although EF6+ now allows mocking directly, so that's less of an issue) and more importantly, should you decide someday to change your database code, it's all in one place...  Without a huge amount of overhead.

It's also a breeze to inject via dependency injection.